# bass not working on Windows 10 with speakers

Tags: windows-10, audio, speakers

I have an HP Envy with Windows 10. When I plug in my external speakers, (into the headphones jack) the sound plays perfectly for about 2 seconds, then the bass completely goes away. I have tried `msconfig` > `services` > `enable all` as recommended, but it didn't fix the problem. I have also tried `start` > `device manager` > `sound, video, and game controllers` > `driver` > `update driver` but it just tells me my driver us up to date, so no success there either. I have had this computer for a few weeks and the speakers were working fine, but they suddenly stopped playing the bass (I have also eliminated the speakers themselves as the problem because they work on all my other devises). Does anyone know how I can get my bass working properly again?

Answer (score 0):

Try these. My friend had a similar problem, I followed the steps in the first link and fixed it. Before you try these; have you updated your OS? It may be a driver problem.

1. [Troubleshooting Sound Problems with External Speakers](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01916592)
2. [my external speakers aren't working](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Audio/my-external-speakers-aren-t-working-hp-beats-audio-pavilion/td-p/1005393/page/3)
3. [no bass through beats audio](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Audio/hp-envy-M7-j020dx-no-bass-through-beats-audio/td-p/3228037)

Comment: Thanks so much, but none of the suggestions you gave me solved my problem. I found a video on YouTube that solved my issue and bass is back! http://youtube.com/watch?v=Rre5Xh2Qywk

Comment: @Mashpoe: That worked for me too.  You might answer your own question with a text-and-graphics description (or do a really good job with just text), so that others can end their search right here.  Then accept your own answer.  Thanks!